# Sokoban with only $k$ boxes

Tags: complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity

*Note: I have posted a hugely expanded version of this question [on cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31077/6973).*

Since a [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) instance with only $k$ boxes has at most $n^{O(k)}$ possible states, the problem lies in [$\operatorname{NSPACE}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#nspace)$[O(k \cdot \log (n))]$. Since the region

```
X    X
X XX XX
X  X  X
XX    X
    XXX
```

has neither boxes nor storage locations and is such that a box can be pushed from the top to exit out the bottom but can't be pushed from the bottom to the top, the problem "Is there a [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Matching) from one given set of $k$ vertices to another given set of $k$ vertices in the [transitive closure of the given directed grid graph](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/pub/allender/plan.ggr.pdf)?" can easily be reduced to the problem I am asking about.

> Is anything else known about the complexity of Sokoban with only $k$ boxes?

In particular, is it the case that solvable instances always have solutions of length $n^{o(k)}$?

I tried to construct a bounded-[counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine) gadget, but aside from realizing that such a gadget would require a box being moved along it when the counter's value is sufficiently large (since otherwise the player could just "pretend" to have incremented or decremented the counter), I wasn't able to get anywhere with that.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound that annoyed; I've toned down the intro (as you apparently noticed). $\:$ I personally like having spacing correspond somewhat with parsing, and otherwise in general making lines in the same paragraph have roughly the same lengths. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I asked a question on Meta about formatting in general, see [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1014/472).